# In GKE, can we specify the zone or region of a persistent volume when we create it through a PVC object

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I want my persistent volume to reside in a specific zone, say us-central1-a, but I want to deploy it through a PVC, not by creating an object of PV directly. Is this possible in GKE?

Comment: Are your node in the same zone? By this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#pd-zones) k8s will choose a random zone to create the disk. What is the requirement to choose the zone? Maybe there are another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @KoopaKiller I want to create a PV in a regional cluster, so there are many zones present, so when I create a PVC, random zones are assigned to their respective PVs. So I want to specify the zone while creating the PVC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you can specify a zone for a PV or PVC, but you can set `volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer` on the StorageClass to ensure that the PV is in the same zone as the pod that uses it.   nodeSelector on the pod can then be used to choose the zone.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ssd
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowVolumeExpansion: true
```

PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Gi
  storageClassName: ssd
```

pod:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone: us-central1-a
  containers:
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Regional persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/regional-pd)

> To enable dynamic provisioning of regional persistent disks, create a StorageClass with the replication-type parameter, and specify zone constraints in allowedTopologies.
>
> For example, the following manifest describes a StorageClass named regionalpd-storageclass that uses standard persistent disks and that replicates data to the europe-west1-b and europe-west1-c zones:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: regionalpd-storageclass
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  replication-type: regional-pd
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - europe-west1-b
    - europe-west1-c
```

> Create a PersistentVolumeClaim object, and use the storageClassName field to refer to the StorageClass you created. For example, the following manifest creates a PersistentVolumeClaim named regional-pvc and references the regionalpd-storageclass

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: regional-pvc
  namespace: testns
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Gi
  storageClassName: regionalpd-storageclass
```

> The following manifest is an example Pod using the previously created PersistentVolumeClaim:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: regional-pvc
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

You can follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-kubernetes-engine-to-deploy-apps-with-regional-persistent-disks) that show you how you can do it

Comment: @RuchidnyaKadam,  if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Regional disks are more expensive than zonal disks.   Also, zonal disks have affinity, so it pins the pod to the zone, which may be a good or bad thing depending on requirements.   It'd be nice to have an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me in GKE:

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard-euw2c
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - europe-west2-c
```

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#allowed-topologies

The key part above is `allowedTopologies`, where I permitted a single zone.

Example PVC:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: hi-europe-west2-c
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: standard-euw2c
```